# Error with OpenSSL when running Python script from command line

Tags: url, openssl, importerror, moviepy, pytube

everyone. I would like to ask for some help with a problem I have been struggling with without any progress. I am creating a small project in my free time. A part of the project is a Python script that downloads a whole Youtube music playlist with pytube and then converts it to audio files with moviepy. When I run the script in PyCharm or in PyCharm's terminal, it works just fine. However, when I try to run it from the command prompt, it returns this exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Programming\youtube_music_extraction\audio_from_ytvideos.py",
> line 41, in 
> download_playlist(playlist_link, destination_folder)   File "C:\Users\denis\Desktop\Programming\youtube_music_extraction\audio_from_ytvideos.py",
> line 30, in download_playlist
> for v in video_urls:   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line
> 71, in **iter**
> curr_item = self[iter_index]   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\helpers.py", line
> 57, in **getitem**
> next_item = next(self.gen)   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py",
> line 281, in url_generator
> for page in self._paginate():   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py",
> line 118, in _paginate
> json.dumps(extract.initial_data(self.html))   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\contrib\playlist.py",
> line 58, in html
> self._html = request.get(self.playlist_url)   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line
> 53, in get
> response = _execute_request(url, headers=extra_headers, timeout=timeout)   File
> "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line
> 37, in _execute_request
> return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
> response = self._open(req, data)   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 539, in _open
> return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in
> _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "C:\Users\denis\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1417, in
> unknown_open
> raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type) urllib.error.URLError:

I must be able to run the script from the command line, because it will be executed by a C# WPF app. So far I have:
-Made sure that I am using the same interpreted in PyCharm and in the command line;
-Tried installing OpenSSL in various different ways: using pip, using an installer from their website;
Nothing has worked so far. I will be incredibly grateful if someone could help me resolve the problem and understand what causes it, so I can become a better programmer.
Thanks in advance!